# Is it possible to transfer adviser cards to my other accounts?

Tags: age-of-empires-online

I'm playing as the Egyptian civilization and I also just started Persians.

In Egyptian civilization, I have a Persian adviser card. How do I transfer it to my Persian account?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can transfer an adviser card by sending a message to yourself and including it as an attachment.